# Как передать переменную enum в тело запроса Post Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, post, enum

Есть enam и контроллер как правильно передать enum через json?

```
public enum Status {

    One,
    Two,
    Three;
}

@PostMapping("/api/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Model> post(
            @RequestBody Status status,
            @PathVariable Long id
    ) {
        logic
        return ResponseEntity.ok(trip);
    }
```

если я отправляю такой json

{"status":"One"}

ошибка Required request body is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хочется передавать такой json объект содержащий поле status

```
{"status":"One"}
```

то предполагается что в приложении есть класс, например такой

```
import lombok.*;

    @ToString
    public class StatusDTO {

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @JsonProperty(value = "status")
        private Status status;

        enum Status {
            One,
            Two,
            Three;
        }
    }
```

в контроллере

```
@RequestBody StatusDTO status
```

Если в контроллере хочется принимать именно объект перечисления, то придется изменить тело запроса

```
["One"]
```

и принимать массив в контроллере

```
@RequestBody Status[] status
```